# How to use checkable auto-exclusive buttons

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qpushbutton

I hope find an answer. I have created an application with Python and PyQt4, and I have made the buttons checkable to select a file or folder from the treeview, and all button are auto-exclusive. The problem is when I choose another tab and check a button from there, the button in the first tab is still checked and I can't call `setchecked(False)`. Any idea how to solve this problem ?

[image]

[image]

archive with the code and the ui used : sorry i don't know how to insert the code here .
[enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8q06u7lerzurlkk/example.rar?dl=0)

[image]

Comment: Please show all the relevant parts of your code. It is very difficult to understand what the problem is from your current description.

Comment: thanks ; the checkable buttons are setup in qt designer and in the script i just connect every button with its code which have no relation with the problem. in the first tab : render tool(see the photo) open button is checked and it unchecked only if i click another button (svae for exp) ; when i go to the second tab : replace mxm and click on mxm folder button ; the open button in the first tab is already checked and work with its code and i can't unchecked it.

Comment: No one can help you if you don't show any code. Brief descriptions and screenshots are not enough.

Comment: ok i will try to create simple version to show the problem

Comment: thank you all ; i solve the problem